# how to clear url arguments in flask after using form

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I currently have a form that when its submitted it redirects with all of the required parameters(see below),

My problem is that when it redirects from the form page to the results page, if I refresh the results page it re runs the logic, and I want the user to have to input the form information again before seeing new results.

javascript redirect:

```
document.location.href = "/results?age=" + encodeURIComponent(userage) + "&price=" + encodeURIComponent(price);
```

python logic:

```
@application.route("/results")
def get_response():
    age = request.args.get("age")
    price = request.args.get("price")
    htmltext = age+price
    return render_template("results.html",html=str(htmltext))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JavaScript history API to remove the url arguments on your page load.

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
url.searchParams.delete('age','price');
window.history.replaceState({},document.title, url);
```